# What is the problem with my code for multiplying two numbers in a different way using Bash?

Tags: bash, for-loop

This is my first time using Bash, so bear with me. I'm using Git Bash in Windows for a college project, trying to rewrite some C code that provides an alternate way of multiplying two numbers "a" and "b" to produce "c". This is what I came up with:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -i a
declare -i b
declare -i c=0
declare -i i=0    # not sure if i have to initialize this as 0?
echo "Please enter a number: "
read a
echo "Please enter a number: "
read b

for i in {1..b}
do
    let "c += a"
done

echo "$a x $b = $c"
```

I think part of the problem is in the for loop, that it only executes once. This is my first time using Bash, and if anyone could find the fault in my knowledge, that would be all I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for i in {1..b}

won't work, because 'b' isn't interpreted as a variable but a character to iterate to.
For instance {a..c} expands to a b c.

To make the brace expansion work:
for i in $(eval echo "{1..$b}")


The let "c += a" won't work either.
let c+=$a might work, but I like ((c+=a)) better.

Another way is this:

`for ((i = 1; i <= b; i++))

do

    ((c += a))

done`

(*might* need to put #!/bin/bash at the top of your script, because sh does less than bash.)

Comment: Thank you. This one worked for me, and it is easier to read in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

There are problems with your loop:

- You can't use `{1..b}`. Even if you had `{1..$b}` it wouldn't work because you would need an `eval`. It's easiest to use the `seq` command instead.
- Your `let` syntax is incorrect.

Try this:

```
for i in $(seq 1 $b)
do
    let c+=$a
done
```

Also, it's not necessary to declare or initialise `i`.

Comment: Oh OK thanks. It's just that on [this page](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-for-loop/) I read that the 'seq' command was only recommended for the older bash version, and all users are recommended to use the curly brackets ({}).

Answer (score 0):

Of course, bash already has multiplication, but I guess you knew that ...

If the absence of "seq" is your issue, you can replace it with something more portable, like

```
c=0

# Print an endless sequence of lines
yes |
# Only take the first $b lines
head -n "$b" |
# Add line number as prefix for each line
nl |
# Read the numbers into i, and the rest of the line into a dummy variable
while read i dummy; do
    # Update the value of c: add line number
    c=`expr "$c" + "$i"`
    echo "$c"
done |
# Read the last number from the while loop
tail -n 1
```

This should be portable to any Bourne-compatible shell.  The `while ... echo ... done | tail -n 1` trick is necessary only if the value of `c` is not exported outside the `while` loop, as is the case in some, but not all, Bource shells.

You can implement a `seq` replacement with a Perl one-liner, but then you might as well write all of this in Perl (or awk, or Python, or what have you).